# QGIS WFS download data limit to window extend not functioning properly

Tags: qgis, wfs, extents

The checkbox under WFS Server Connections setup that should control the amount of data that is going to be downloaded from WFS doesn't react as it should. 
[image]

Each time I tried to visualize the data within the bounding box it firstly take to much time and secondly when I save it on my hard disk and open again I found many polygons that are outside my desired area. Plus in my bbox not all vectors are present. 
I tried to control the WFS download via "Build query" using these expressions but not got what I wanted:

```
BBOX(STGeomFromText('POINT(1381933 4375059)', 3003), STGeomFromText('POINT(1381933 4375059)', 3003))
ST_SetSRID((ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(1381933,4375059), ST_Point(1541675,4461553))), 3003)
ST_AsText(ST_MakeEnvelope(1381933,4375059, 1541675,4461553, 3003))
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1381933 4375059)', 3003), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1381933 4375059)', 3003))
```

[image]

Above shown coordinates are coming from one Italian WFS but I also tried those scripts at several different WFSs and the result was the same.

This link looks promising but actually not works:
[QGIS Spatial Filter (boundary box)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiBQg8diLBU)

```
ST_Within(geometry,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(1381933,4375059), ST_Point(1541675,4461553)), 3003))
```

The "geometry" must be defined first.

Any ideas how to force the WFS to download only the data within bbox. Many similar questions exists at the web but non of them answered directly how to do it or why those scripts are not filtering the data. Would be better if one can describe how to do it via available QGIS UI (SQL Query Composer) or to exactly explain how to include the bbox into the WFS's link and access the portal directly with bbox defined in it. 
I also tried to achieve this by controlling the "Maximum number of features" and "Page size" (10000 and 100 respectively) but the problem remains. 
My Network General settings are:
Time out for network requests (ms): 240000
and Cache settings Size (KiB): 1024000
[image]

Comment: If you need a file copy of the data just download it directly using curl, wget or ogr2ogr

Comment: Would be super nice if you can direct me to some guideline link where I can learn how to use those queries you mentioned. Or to write here in short: where to write them (in qgis's python console, in OSGeo4W console, or somewhere else) and how to run it. Tx

Comment: Have you read the wfs spec?

Comment: Yes I have (I used getcapabilities function). What I should pay attention to?

Comment: the getfeatures section

Comment: ows:Operation name="GetFeature">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:type="simple"

Type "simple" means a simple link, so it is not possible to define bbox?

Comment: I managed to control one Sweden WFS by adding the bbox into the web link it self and it works but I still having the problem with my desired WFS (the one locked with password). 
I compared those two WFSs and noticed they are not the same when we talk about GetFeatures part of their specification.

Comment: Does that mean there are different WFSs with different saving possibilities? If the answer is yes, where I can see that in the WFS specification?